# Char value representation in JVM

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, character

How is the char value represented in JVM? Let's say

```
char ch = 'c';
```

How is the **value of ch** represented as a **16-bit unsigned integer** in JVM?

Answer (score 8):

<sup>**Too Long; Didn't Read;**</sup>
      <sup>**1**. Characters in java are represented using UTF-16</sup>
      <sup>**2**. As implied by the name, one char is 16 bit in size</sup>
      <sup>**3**. The default value of a `char` is 0.</sup>

---

To quote the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) about `char`s:

> #### Unicode Character Representations
>
> The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object
>   encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which
>   defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode
>   standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose
>   representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code
>   points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value.
>   (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode standard.)
>
> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to
>   as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points
>   are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java
>   2 platform **uses the UTF-16 representation** in char arrays and in the
>   String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary
>   characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from
>   the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the
>   low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).
>
> A char value, therefore, represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)
>   code points, including the surrogate code points, or code **units of the
>   UTF-16 encoding**. An int value represents all Unicode code points,
>   including supplementary code points. The lower (least significant) 21
>   bits of int are used to represent Unicode code points and the upper
>   (most significant) 11 bits must be zero. Unless otherwise specified,
>   the behavior with respect to supplementary characters and surrogate
>   char values is as follows:
>
> The methods that only accept a char value cannot support supplementary
>   characters. They treat char values from the surrogate ranges as
>   undefined characters. For example, Character.isLetter('\uD840')
>   returns false, even though this specific value if followed by any
>   low-surrogate value in a string would represent a letter. The methods
>   that accept an int value support all Unicode characters, including
>   supplementary characters. For example, Character.isLetter(0x2F81A)
>   returns true because the code point value represents a letter (a CJK
>   ideograph). In the J2SE API documentation, Unicode code point is used
>   for character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF, and
>   Unicode code unit is used for **16-bit char values that are code units
>   of the UTF-16 encoding**. For more information on Unicode terminology,
>   refer to the Unicode Glossary.

Comment: Copypaste of the relevant documentation (when cited) is fair game.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is stored as a UTF-16 codepoint, a two-byte integer.

So a lower-case 'c' is 99 (decimal) or 0x0063 (hex).

Comment: so it means the unicode value of c is 0x0063 which is 99 (int form). Now this 99 will be stored as 2 byte integer(0000000001100011)?

Comment: can u explain the conversion of char 'c' to its 16-bit representation?

Comment: 0x0063 (decimal 99) is the Unicode codepoint for 'c'. Nothing more to be explained...

Answer (score 0):

**1.** char is represented in Java as a **16 bit Unicode** value.

**2.** The default value of char is **'\u0000'**